# multiple data frames

Tags: python, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have multiple data frames. For suppose consider I have three data frames:-

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'bca', 'cab'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[11, 12, 13], [4, 45, 46], [7, 48, 49]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'acb', 'bac'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 55, 96], [7, 88, 79]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'ca', 'gac'])
```

Now I want to join three data frames based on column  `'abc'` where the join condition is `'outer'` for the first two data frames and the result of this two has to join with `df3` with join condition `'inner`'. For this, I can use lambda reduce to join three data frames with one condition but how to join when there are two join conditions?

code:-

```
when join condition is 'outer'
    data_frames = [df1, df2,df3]
    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['abc'],
                                                how='outer'), data_frames)
```

result:-

```
abc bca cab acb bac ca  gac
0   1   2.0 3.0 NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
1   4   5.0 6.0 45.0    46.0    55.0    96.0
2   7   8.0 9.0 48.0    49.0    88.0    79.0
3   11  NaN NaN 12.0    13.0    NaN NaN
```

but when two conditions are given :-

```
data_frames = [df1, df2,df3]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['abc'],
                                            how='outer','inner'), data_frames)
```

error:-

```
 how='outer','inner'), data_frames)
               ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I know that we can't give two condtions but what is the best way to give two condtional satement.(Note:- this is just for three dataframes but I am looking for multiple data frames)

Execpted output:-

```
abc  bca  cab   acb   bac  ca  gac
0    1  2.0  3.0   NaN   NaN   2    3
1    4  5.0  6.0  45.0  46.0  55   96
2    7  8.0  9.0  48.0  49.0  88   79
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make an iterator with your join types and use `next` to get each how.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'bca', 'cab'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[11, 12, 13], [4, 45, 46], [7, 48, 49]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'acb', 'bac'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 55, 96], [7, 88, 79]]),
                   columns=['abc', 'ca', 'gac'])

data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]
merge_hows = iter(['outer', 'inner'])
df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['abc'],
                                                how=next(merge_hows)), data_frames)

print(df_merged)
```

Output:

```
   abc  bca  cab   acb   bac  ca  gac
0    1  2.0  3.0   NaN   NaN   2    3
1    4  5.0  6.0  45.0  46.0  55   96
2    7  8.0  9.0  48.0  49.0  88   79
```